# Prisma Client could not locate the Query Engine for runtime debian-openssl-3.0.x

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, openssl, debian, prisma

The Prisma client works on localhost but not on the production server. How to fix this error? I'm using Webpack and GitLab Runner for deployment. I tried to some other ways but it doesn't fix the issue.
**Production server log:**

```
{
    "level": "error",
    "message": "\nInvalid `prisma.event.findMany()` invocation:\n\n\nPrisma Client could not locate the Query Engine for runtime \"debian-openssl-3.0.x\".\n\nThis is likely caused by a bundler that has not copied \"libquery_engine-debian-openssl-3.0.x.so.node\" next to the resulting bundle.\nEnsure that \"libquery_engine-debian-openssl-3.0.x.so.node\" has been copied next to the bundle or in \"node_modules/.prisma/client\".\n\nWe would appreciate if you could take the time to share some information with us.\nPlease help us by answering a few questions: https://pris.ly/engine-not-found-bundler-investigation\n\nThe following locations have been searched:\n  /root/node_modules/.prisma/client\n  /var/www\n  /home/gitlab-runner/builds/bPytr7JzY/0/mbook-microservices/mbook-analytics/node_modules/@prisma/client\n  /.prisma/client\n  /tmp/prisma-engines",
    "target": "event.findMany",
    "timestamp": "2024-01-27T01:36:29.514Z"
}
```

**More information:**

```
Ubuntu 23.10 x64
Node.js 20.10.0
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npx webpack",
  ...
}
"dependencies": {
  "@prisma/client": "^5.8.1",
  ...
}
```

**schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x", "debian-openssl-3.0.x", "linux-musl", "linux-musl-openssl-3.0.x"]
}
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
script:
  - npm install
  - npx prisma generate
  - npm run build
```